# Sorting number in multiple range usin MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, sorting

I am developing an educational site with requires sorting by range of numbers. I need some help on how to sort my data into the range as listed below.
581 is the highest, 604 is the lowest. It starts with 604 to 582, and begin again with 1 until 581.

```
(Highest) 581 580 579.   .   . 3     2   1   582     .   .   .   602     603     604    (Lowest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one idea...

```
SELECT * FROM ints;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
| 9 |
+---+

SELECT i,CASE WHEN i < 5 THEN 1000-i ELSE i END x FROM ints ORDER BY x;
+---+------+
| i | x    |
+---+------+
| 5 |    5 |
| 6 |    6 |
| 7 |    7 |
| 8 |    8 |
| 9 |    9 |
| 4 |  996 |
| 3 |  997 |
| 2 |  998 |
| 1 |  999 |
| 0 | 1000 |
+---+------+
```

You can also write this as...

```
SELECT i FROM ints ORDER BY CASE WHEN i < 5 THEN 1000-i ELSE i END;
```